# Updating Datatable to EXISTING global database connection

Tags: sql, wpf, vb.net, ado.net

I am using Microsoft Visual Basic 2010 Express. I have a WPF-based project. I have a successful connection to a database in Database Explorer, and a working existing Data Source in Data Sources.

I created a datatable from the datasource using this code:

```
Dim roster_table As New DataTable("AGENT_ROSTER")
```

I can manipulate this datatable just fine, but I cannot figure out how to save its data to my database (agentroster.sdf) since the connection is on a global level, and isn't declared in this particular window.

**How do I update this database from the datatable on this window?**

By the way, I tried creating a connection on this window's code, using the exact same connection string as the successful globally-connected database, yet it said that it couldn't connect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tough to say given the limited information you provided. You should also note that there are a lot of ways to do this. However the most basic way is to use a table adapter. Once you've set the Update, Insert and Delete commands you call its `Update` method.

Here's an [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171933%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) that might help you further

Comment: You'd be surprised to know that your answer actually helped me solve! I sometimes have a tough time connecting these concepts with my project. The code I used was "Dim table_adaptor As New AGENT_ROSTERTableAdaptors.AGENT_ROSTERTableAdaptor" My only other question is...should that work?

Comment: @JasonMc92. Yep, that looks right. Once you've gained some comfort with ADO.NET, it may be worth while at what other [people are doing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/363222/is-everyone-here-jumping-on-the-orm-band-wagon)